# Executing drupal file using shell_exec

Tags: hooks

I wish know whether a drupal function/file can be executed using 'shell_exec()' from another drupal function.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal imposes no limits on how you can use php. If it's possible to do what you need to do in php, it's possible in Drupal.

There are no Drupal-specific API methods to help execute code through the shell, so just approach this as you would if Drupal wasn't involved.

A simple method, depending on what you need to do, might be to install Drush and invoke commands using that. Then the bootstrap/file includes will be handled for you automatically and you'll need to write less boilerplate code.

Answer (score 2):

I run command using php function [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

```
$command_save = 'mysqldump --defaults-file='.$config_file.' '.$database_name.' > '.$db_dump_file;

exec($command_save, $output = array(), $res_save);
```

where `$config_file` - path to configuration file consists login and password for connect to DB, 
`$database_name` - name of DB, 
`$db_dump_file` - dump DB file name

Also you can run command using [ssh2_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php)

```
  $server = "localhost";
  $username = "user";
  $password = "pass";

  $connection = ssh2_connect($server, 22);

  if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password)) {

    $command = 'drush up --security-only -y';

    // Run a command that will probably write to stderr (unless you have a folder named /hom)
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
    $errorStream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);

    // Enable blocking for both streams
    stream_set_blocking($errorStream, true);
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);

    // Whichever of the two below commands is listed first will receive its appropriate output.  The second command receives nothing
    $result = stream_get_contents($stream);
    $result_error = stream_get_contents($errorStream);

    // Close the streams       
    fclose($errorStream);
    fclose($stream);
  }
```

I use this method because if I try run drush command with exec() function I have some troubles (Drupal runs from user which hasn't necessary privileges). And for using this method you need to install libssh2 at the server.