# How to run an executable from within a Drupal Controller?

Tags: 8

I'm working on a controller that when called upon will take a screenshot of the main page of my site. I'm attempting this by calling Chrome in headless mode via the PHP shell_exec() function.

```
$command = 'google-chrome --headless --no-sandbox --screenshot=./pic2.png --window-size=600,400 http://localhost/';    
$output = shell_exec($command);        
ksm($output);
```

Unfortunatley this doesn't seem to work inside my Drupal controller. This will however work just fine in a php script outside of Drupal. Also, if I just try to read the version with my Drupal Controller then it does work. Command to read version:

```
$command = 'google-chrome --product-version';
```

I'm assuming there's some security feature that prevents Drupal from triggering an external executable (understandable). Is there a safe way around this or am I just going about this the wrong way? Thanks!

Comment: > Drupal imposes no limits on how you can use php. If it's possible to do what you need to do in php, it's possible in Drupal.
[Source](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/222478/5284). Even though this answer is from 2016 I think it's still valid as far as I'm aware. Are you just not seeing output from `ksm()`? Have you tried a `die();` just after it to see if you're not being caught out by form redirects or such?

Comment: This is doable, it was done in an old PhantomJS module.

Comment: Does your executing web server user have permissions to execute that command?

Comment: I gave the google-chrome process 777 permissions to see if that might help. No change in result, it still won't run.